# Is this motivational quote in C, using conditional statements, correct?

Tags: c++, c

I was reading a post here, but I guess it was confuse and bad written. So I will give a shot here because I still want to find out the answer. Hopefully, I won't receive that many downvotes.

Here's the thing, there is this motivational funny quote:

```
if (sad() == true) {
    sad().stop;
    beAwesome();
}
```

As far as I'm concerned this is C or C++. I guess both languages would work.
So my main question here is: would this work in C? Assuming, of course, the variables exists.
If so, could this be written also as the code below?

```
if sad() {
    sad().stop;
    beAwesome();
}
```

EDIT: I got already two downvotes... since I'm new here, can someone please help me to understand my mistake here.

Comment: Try compiling your code and you’ll find out.

Comment: Hover over the ‘downvote’ button to find out some description of what a downvote means. Then read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: C and C++ are *completely different languages*, so please don't conflate them. When you lump them together and presume they're the same you are going to ruffle a lot of feathers.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Good thoughs, but `error: 'sad()' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/874dc517b7b6c070. In C++ this is trivial

Comment: The code `if sad() {` is invalid in both C and C++; you must have parentheses around the condition — `if (sad()) {`.

Comment: You have tagged both C and C++.  Are you mixing them?  I highly recommend not mixing the languages unless you absolutely need to and have a lot of experience in both languages, **and know the differences between the two**.

Comment: Please include the function declaration for `sad()`.

Comment: The `sad()` needs to return a reference to a class or structure (unless it is a nasty macro).  The "." operator is used to refer to members of a class or structure.  BTW, the C language does not have references.

Answer (score 6):

The first variant is not valid C. The reason is that if `sad()` returns something that can be compared to `true`, it cannot be a `struct`. And it needs to be a struct for `sad().stop` to be valid. It is valid C++, since you can overload the comparison operator of a struct or class to allow it to compare to `true`.

The second part is not valid in C or C++ without using a macro to ensure there are parentheses around the condition:

```
#define sad() (...)
```

Comment: Once you go into the fantasy world of macros anything is possible and nothing makes sense any more. Monkeys can fly. Unicorns exist. `true` can be `false`.

Comment: @tadman That's not actually, er, true.

Comment: To some extent, it is. I vaguely recall that you have to jump through hoops, but it is possible to redefine `true` to evaluate to `false`, and vice verssa.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The Obfuscated C contest has documented many crimes of this sort.

Comment: I once saw a pretty good mock-up of Java code in a C program that compiled  and did what you'd expect from the same Java code. It wasn't very long, but it proved the point.

Comment: @MooingDuck That would have undefined behaviour. You can't redefine keywords. (N.B. I'm talking about C++ specifically.). And more generally you just can't do "anything" with macros ;)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings At least in C, those aren't keywords, but you're right about C++

Comment: @G.Sliepen I'm sorry, but [you are mistaken](http://eel.is/c++draft/macro.names#2). The preprocessor is _part of the language_, and is not immune from its rules, some of which specifically apply to it.

Comment: @G.Sliepen The paragraph I linked you to makes no such provision. You cannot redefine a keyword in C++, period. Simples!

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I stand corrected!